# Multiple jQuery tabs on one page...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

All I want to do is have multiple tabbed areas on the same page, and use a class in the JS to work them all. I don't want to have to work with manually adding separate IDs to the JS to activate the tabs.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/V7a2C/2/

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<aside id="0" class="widget tabbed popular-articles">
    <header>
        <h1 class="widget-title">Popular Articles 1</h1>
        <a href="#" class="more">More</a>

        <ul class="tab-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Read</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Emailed</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab read first active">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The IT Talent Problem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Finance Leaders Bemoan Talent Shortage</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">A Powerful Stock-Price Predictor</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The Great Pension Derisking</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">It's All in the Game</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab emailed second">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Special Report: Benchmarking Tech</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The IT Talent Problem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The Great Pension Derisking</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">A Powerful Stock-Price Predictor</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">It's All in the Game</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
<aside id="1" class="widget tabbed popular-articles">
    <header>
        <h1 class="widget-title">Popular Articles 2</h1>
        <a href="#" class="more">More</a>

        <ul class="tab-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Read</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Emailed</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="tab1b" class="tab read first active">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The IT Talent Problem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Finance Leaders Bemoan Talent Shortage</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">A Powerful Stock-Price Predictor</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The Great Pension Derisking</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">It's All in the Game</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2b" class="tab emailed second">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Special Report: Benchmarking Tech</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The IT Talent Problem</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">The Great Pension Derisking</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">A Powerful Stock-Price Predictor</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">It's All in the Game</a>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

JS

```
$('.tab-nav li a').click(function(){

    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    var tabs = $(this).parents('aside');

    $(this).parent('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    tabs.find('.tab').removeClass('active');
    $(currentTab).addClass('active');
    console.log(tabs.find('.tab'));
    var tabs = $(this).parents('aside');
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but you actually find [jQueryUI TABS](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) more complicated and harassing than this code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah, if you can, just use an already implemented version of tabs.

Comment: Actually, I do much prefer [10 lines of javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668431/737377) to including yet another library for something as simple as this. Plus I am trying to learn how it all works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the links and tabs are in the same order, because this code uses the index of the title that is clicked on to determine the index of the tab to show:

```
$('.tab-nav li a').click(function(){

    var that = $(this); //cache when you can
    var tabIndex = that.parent().index();
    var tabs = that.parents('aside').find('.tab');

    that.parent('li').siblings().removeClass('active');
    that.parent('li').addClass('active');
    tabs.removeClass('active');
    tabs.eq(tabIndex).addClass('active');
    return false;

});
```

Alternatively you can run some javascript to give all tabs and titles matching ID's beforehand, or just use an outside library like jQuery-UI tabs.

Comment: Sorry, now it should work, as long as tab groups are in separate aside tags.

Comment: Delete all your id's and everything works as long as the tabs titles and tab content divs are in the same order--this code uses the index of the title that is clicked on to determine the index of the tab to show.

Comment: Seems to work like a charm! Thank you very much for taking the time. I'm working on leveling up my JS, but in the meantime I still have to work. :)

Comment: Awesome. Good luck on your future coding endeavors!

Comment: Yes, for the most part. Still reading up on the `.index()`, which seems to be the key to making multiple instances work.

Comment: Well, the way jQuery works, you'll only be working inside the "aside" tag that your tab-nav is in, no matter what. If you correct the id's per the other guy's answer, multiple instances work anyway. `index()` is the key to not using id's at all, and saving yourself the time and extra upkeep to manually add id's. :)

Comment: Thank you. Not having to manually add ID's is exactly it. I'm using this in a WordPress widget, so it wouldn't make sense to have to add ID's anytime a tabbed widget is created or changed. Thanks again for the quick help.

Answer (score 0):

You had a small mistake in giving the `href` values for the second tab, it should be `tab1b` and `tab2b`

```
<header>
    <h1 class="widget-title">Popular Articles 2</h1>
    <a href="#" class="more">More</a>

    <ul class="tab-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1b">Read</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2b">Emailed</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kS3zV/)